# CKEditor - Editable content CSS interferes with editor toolbar styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor to allow users to edit HTML documents. I need to allow the users to be able to place any kind of CSS or HTML into their documents. When the user's document CSS has `!important` rules they change the styling of the CKEditor toolbar.

This can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/hqpfjzyr/1/

Click on the "Link Preview" and you'll see the buttons of the toolbar are also red.

This behavior is described by the CKEditor docs here (https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/skin_sdk_reset.html) but I can't seem to figure out how to apply it. My skin stylesheet includes a `reset.css` but it doesn't seem to affect the styling.

The only thing that I can think of is to add more CSS targeting the toolbar and explicitly setting every attribute to the correct value with `!important` rules but that seems like a daunting task.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

> This behavior is described by the CKEditor docs here (https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/skin_sdk_reset.html) but I can't seem to figure out how to apply it. My skin stylesheet includes a reset.css but it doesn't seem to affect the styling.

What is described on CKEditor docs doesn't include case with `!important` flag, because it can't work like you want to. This flag overwrites other css rules including ones in reset file. If you still want to use `!important` inside editor you might consider to use classic editor instead of inline. Change `CKEDITOR.inline(` to `CKEDITOR.replace`. How does that help? Classic editor is rendered inside iframe, which has separate styles that can't affect anything outside it.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Unfortunately, the classic editor doesn't work for my use case. Noted about the reset file not handling `!important` rules.